# bitwise negation operator for ulong returns uint

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, ulong

I want to remove the last set bit of a ulong.  Here's what I do:

```
ulong mydata;
...
ulong t = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < ulongSizeBits; i++)
{
    if ((myData&t)!=0)
    {
        mydata = mydata & (~t);
        break;
    }
    t <<= 1;
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't work as advertised. Let's do another experiment:

```
        var test = 1U;
        var t1 = ~test;
        var t = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            Console.Write((t&t1)!=0?1:0);
            t <<= 1;
        }
```

The output will be not `01111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` as expected, but `0111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000`. It appears, that  bitwise not converts ulong to uint or something.

What is the best way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1U` is not `ulong`. It's `uint`. Declare `test` and `t` as `ulong` and you'll get what you need:

```
var test = 1UL;
var t1 = ~test;
var t = 1UL;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    Console.Write((t & t1) != 0 ? 1 : 0);
    t <<= 1;
}
```

prints

```
01111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: Thanks! Just did a quick search and found some more bugs!

Comment: Or even better, when types are this critical: do not use `var`.

Comment: That's the first time I got my fingers burned by `var`